# Task<T>, Why does Test swallow the exception and loop forever, and Test_1 throws the exception as expected?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I wanted to do some tests with C# Task to see an exception get swallowed under two different scenarios.

So, can someone explain, why Test swallows the exception and loops forever, and Test_1 throws the exception as expected?

I would love to hear everyone's explanation.

```
Test();   // Swallows the exception

Test_1(); // Throws the exception
```

Thanks

```
try
{
 Test();   // Swallows the exception
}
catch
{
 ; //Breakpoint
}

try
{
 Test_1(); // Throws the exception
}
catch
{
 ; //Breakpoint
}


Test()
{
    SomeMethod<int>(() =>  {
                       Thread.Sleep(5000);
                       throw new Exception();
                       return 0
                      });

    while (true)
    {
    }
}

Test_1()
{
    SomeMethod_1<int>(() =>  {
                         Thread.Sleep(5000);
                         throw new Exception();
                         return 0
                        });

    while (true)
    {
    }
}


T SomeMethod<T>(Func<T> function) // Note: This returns immediately
{
  var testTask = new Task<T>(function);

  testTask.Start();

  return default(T); 

}

T SomeMethod_1<T>(Func<T> function) // Note: This wait's for result
{
  var testTask = new Task<T>(function);

  testTask.Start();

  return testTask.Result; 

}
```

Comment: You already stated the answer in your comment: `// Note: This waits for result`

Comment: *Never* swallow exceptions. Especially not a catch all / catch (Exception). It is a deadly sin of exception handling. Please refer to these two articles on how to do it properly: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher Thanks. I was just trying to keep the example short.

Comment: The problem with your theory is that, so long as testTask holds a reference to that Task object, it won't get garbage collected.  Garbage collection only takes place on an object when you are no longer holding references to it.

Comment: @Robert Harvey So, what your saying is not "You already stated the answer", it's that Test is not swallowing the exception, it's that Test() was still holding the reference. When Test() finishes execution and execution moves on to Test_1, garbage collection will happen and the exception will happen. Right? E.g, if I put a timeout in Test()'s while loop to end it's execution.

Comment: Yes, more or less.

Answer (score -1):

Your example is an overly complicated version of the following simplified example:

```
// A
_ = Task.Run(() => throw new Exception());
```

vs

```
// B
Task.Run(() => throw new Exception()).Wait();
```

The (A) swallows the exception, because the `Task` is launched in a fire-and-forget fashion. The application launches the task, and then immediately
and deliberately loses track of it, because it doesn't care about the task's outcome.

The (B) propagates the exception, because the application waits the `Task` to complete before continuing.

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nJFpRP).

That's all about it.